# HTTP 303 (SeeOther): GET Works, POST Fails

Tags: python, http, http-headers, web.py

I am trying to perform a simple action:

1. POST to a URL
2. Return HTTP 303 (SeeOther)
3. GET from new URL

From what I can tell, this is a pretty standard practice:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Also, it would seem that SeeOther is designed to work this way:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4

I'm using web.py as my server-side controller, but I suspect that it's not the issue. If I GET, SeeOther works flawlessly as expected. If I POST to the same URL, the browser fails to redirect or load anything at all.

Thinking it was a browser issue, I tried both IE9 and Google Chrome (v23 ish). Both have the same issue.

Thinking web.py might be serving the page incorrectly, or generating a bad URL, I used telnet to examine the headers. I found this:

HTTP GET (this works in the browser):

```
GET /Users/1 HTTP/1.1
HOST: domain.com

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2012 18:07:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Cache-control: no-cache
Location: http://domain.com/Users
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

HTTP POST (this does not work in the browser):

```
POST /Users/1 HTTP/1.1
HOST: domain.com

HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Mon, 24 Dec 2012 18:12:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Cache-control: no-cache
Location: http://domain.com/Users
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

Another thing that could be throwing a wrench in the works:
I'm using mod-rewrite so that the user-visible domain.com/Users/1 is actually domain.com/control.py/Users/1

There may be more information/troubleshooting that I have, but I'm drawing a blank right now.

**The Question:**

Why does this work with a GET request, but not a POST request? Am I missing a response header somewhere?

**EDIT:**

Using IE9 Developer Tools and Chrome's Inspector, it looks like the 303 isn't coming back to the browser after a POST. However, I can see the 303 come in when I do a GET request.

However, after looking more closely at Chrome's Inspector, I saw the ability to log every request (don't clear w/ each page call). This allowed me to see that for some reason, my POST request looks like it's failing. Again - GET works just fine.

Comment: what do you see in the Chrome Inspector? Is the 303 received client-side? Chrome would show an error in the console if you have a redirect loop, for example.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Updated the question to contain answers to your questions. Also, this is my first ever question on here, so I don't know whether it'd have been more appropriate to answer in a comment? I figured putting more details in the question makes it easier for future readers...

Comment: It's ok like this. How is the POST request failing?

Comment: Interesting... I tried resonding to the POST with a normal 200 + some text in the body. While this loads in IE9, it times out in Chrome. Both take about 15s before loading or giving up.

I believe I've just unearthed a new problem haha

Comment: without the code you created on the server side, it is difficult to know why your POST is failing. Could you post the server code part addressing your post?

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that this isn't your issue, but since you don't have your code posted I'll take a shot (just in case).

Since you're using web.py, do you have the POST method defined on your object?

i.e.

```
urls = (
    '/page', 'page'
)

class page:

    def POST(self):
        # Do something

    def GET(self):
        # Do something else
```

Comment: I forgot to update this question - I found that the problem isn't with redirects. The underlying problem is actually that the browser fails to receive POST requests from my webpy app entirely. I found the issue to be distinct enough that I created another thread for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132343/http-post-response-fails-using-web-py