# Correct way to return JSON response from POST request with web.py

Tags: python, json, web.py, httplib

I have a web.py server.

I handle post requests like this:

```
class Endpoint(object):
    def POST(self):
        received_payload = web.data()
        # Do things with the payload (a JSON) --- I receive the payload correctly
        response = {"Response": "Good"}
        # I also tried returning the dictionary directly and building my own requests.Response object
        return json.dumps(response)
```

I am able to correctly receive and process the payload I send to the server, but I do not receive the response.

On the client side, I do this:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
response = s.post(url=url, json=payload)
```

The request reaches the server, and delivers the payload correctly. However, I get this error:

```
    response = s.post(url=url, json=payload)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 511, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

I did some research, finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297408/badstatusline-exception-raised-when-returning-reply-from-server-in-python-3) and [this](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx)

I tried the approach suggested in the first link, but I get the same error. It might be because I am using Python 2.7 while the original post is about Python 3. I also tried, based on the second link, to set the output field in `web.ctx` however, I get the same error.

---

What is the correct way to return a JSON as a response to a POST request?

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513446/webpy-how-to-serve-json

Comment: Yes, and this works correctly with GET requests. If I GET a json, I receive it. My problem is with POST requests. I am able to deliver a payload, but the response of the POST request generates an error on the client side.

Comment: The server is responding with a status code your client cant understand. Try to use fiddler, or wireshark to see exactly what the server is sendind to you. Its probably some malformed header/url

Comment: I believe you are right - I changed my code quite a bit since posting this, but in order to get responses going, I had to remove anything that modified context in web.py